# Channel left bar is disruptive

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, sidebar

After signing up for Channels, I find that a hefty percentage of the left margin is blank most of the time.

The content of the side bar is visible and *very occasionally* useful when you are at the top of the page, but when you scroll down, as most of us often do, it simply eats a slice of your display.  In my current browser window, the slice is around 15%:

[image: Stack Overflow main page screen shot, scrolled down]

Adding insult to injury, the layout is pretty crufty (the divider is too close to the question title when you are at the top of the page, there are little lines which end in the middle of nowhere, etc) although those things could of course be fixed separately.

Could you please just turn it off, or make it less intrusive?

Comment: I was pretty sure there already *was* a question on Meta about this, but I couldn't find it. Sorry if this is a duplicate.

Comment: And before someone suggests I maximize my browser window to make the percentage smaller, I hate you for thinking *anyone* should *ever* run anything maximized, and you are *entirely* missing the point.

Comment: The people that suggest maximising windows are also the people that have massive widescreen monitors and can't understand that some people are stuck with old crappy ones. This issue (I assume) is present on smaller monitors too for those of us without that luxury.

Comment: Have you tried maximizing the window? That way you could make the percentage smaller.

Comment: You could use a browser that provides user css via settings or extensions. `#content { width:auto } #question img { margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; display: inline-block; max-width: 728px; }`  Not very useful if you use a lot of different browsers or user css not possible.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth You should definitely try jQuery.

Comment: I run my browser on the top right quarter of a FullHd screen. I use the browser when waiting for stuff on the other three quarters to happen. Maximizing the browser window won't do. Twitch can handle it. Youtube can handle it. SE chat can handle it. SO main, less so.

Comment: @tripleee What browser are you using? I don't see the janky layout on current versions of Chrome, FireFox or Safari.

Comment: @JoeFriend I saw the same layout bugs yesterday when making the window narrow enough, but I don't see them now. Maybe they were fixed in the meantime.

Comment: @MadScientist In any case, this will go away when we enable responsiveness (or at least be replaced with different bugs).

Comment: The screen shot was produced in Chrome on a High Sierra Mac.

Comment: Do you want a mandatory sticky top bar? Because that's how you get a mandatory sticky top bar.

Comment: I specifically and immediately turned off the sticky top bar when that became possible; so no, that's not my preferred solution. I realize that "empty space is useless" could be worked around by making the *slightly* useful content sticky, but I would absolutely prefer for the menu-like structure to actually be a menu which disappears when it's not active.

Comment: I note that this is now [meta-tag:status-completed] in that you can turn off the left side bar in your per-site preferences. The ["responsive" rollout](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes) introduces new annoyances to compensate.

Comment: Even with the left column turned off, I'm seeing some very wide, empty left and right margins using Safari. Looks like the width of the content is limited, so extra space is just blank margins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The left nav can be turned off in your preferences now...

[image: Hide Left Navigation Checkbox]

...and it will be replaced with a menu to the left of the Stack Overflow logo in the top bar.

[image: Menu Replacement]